# In simple terms, what is the advantage of a Virtual Kubelet?

Tags: kubernetes, azure, virtual-kubelet

I have read about the [Virtual Kubelet](https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/virtual-kubelet) project.

I can see that it allows you to *delegate* from Kubernetes to an Azure Container Instance (ACI), that it allows you to deploy both unix/windows boxes, that it will enable "billing by the second".

I'm quite new to Kubernetes and I am struggling understand the advantages in simple terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a look at some old questions people might find, I accept that you either solved this a long time ago or moved on!

"In simple terms..." well, yes. It's hard to talk about this without it heading into abstrations, management planes, and similar mind-fogging terminology. In fact, I may be about to fail in describing it without at least some jargon, but it's limited to *only jargon you'll already know if this tech will be useful to you*.

The simple version is that Virtural Kubelet lets you take advantage of serverless platforms or event-driven platforms acrorss providers (Azure, AWS, GCP).

The idea is that it brings scalability and cost benefits.